# Azure Devops listing numerous packages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs

We have `Azure Devops` for our repository needs and i went into the `Artifacts` section.

To my surprise there was a 100 of packages that somehow have been added to this area and i dont know why.

When clicking a package under **Provenance** i see `Build` with a link to the `Pipelines` but this didnt give a lot away as to how the packages ended up here?

Below this i see the **Code** menu which with links to `branches` (and `yml` file) but would be great if anyone could give me reasons to why this is happening or what setting i need to look at?

Happy to provide more info if required but i dont know what someone may need to narrow this down?

Comment: It's probably caching upstream sources. What *type* of packages are you talking about?